# iPod classic 4th gen (A1059) not recognized by Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mount, 16.10, music, ipod, rockbox

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.10 on my portable LACIE hard drive.  It works perfectly except for one thing: my iPod 4th gen cannot be recognized by Ubuntu.  The iPod has iPod linux (unpartitioned), Rockbox, and the default iPod software on my iPod, has a 32 GB SSD and is formatted as a Winpod.

Why isn't my computer automatically mounting my iPod, and what can I do to get my iPod to mount?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` and `sudo lsblk -f` with the iPod connected (via USB I presume)? Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could, I actually swapped to a different computer so Im unable to currently.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the output of `ts="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T')"`, then connect your iPod, wait 5 seconds, then `journalctl -x --since="$ts"`. This will show us the system log entries.

Comment: I'll try...Last time I did this I woke up to my laptop completely drained.  It may display some sort of different output since its i386, not i686

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the command `sudo fsck.vfat -a -l -v /dev/sdc2` and it seemed to mount when I put the CF card into the computer. When I later plugged the entire iPod in and ran the same command, this confirmed that it worked.

I thought I'd have to type it in every time, but I don't. Anyways, whoever wants to actually do this can now.